# How stream processor (low level API) source processor gets data from topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am novice to kafka stream processor, and came across the key-concept of "topology".

I created source processor which reads from a "source-topic" like this:

```
Topology topology = new Topology();
topology.addSource("SOURCE", "source-topic");
```

The above snippet would create (if my understanding is correct) a source stream processor named "SOURCE" and would listen for kafka topic "source-topic".

I didn't write any code for this "SOURCE" stream-processor, how is it able to get the messages from kafka topic? Is it a "special" type of stream-processor which is taken care by kafka stream API itself?

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Check out the docs: https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [topology](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html) starts from a source node to get data from Kafka, then contains a bunch of processor nodes to perform transformations and finally ends with a sink node to write transformed data into Kafka.

`addSource()` will create a source node in your topology. A source node consumes records from the topic specified and passes them on to the next nodes in the topology. It does not do any other logic. Under the cover, a source node will start a Kafka Consumer to get the records.

The Kafka Streams API enables you to focus on your logic (in the processors) instead of dealing with Consumers and Producers.

Answer (score 0):

```
topology.addSource("SOURCE", "source-topic");
```

Above "SOURCE" is just a name. You can refer the [Topology](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/Topology.html) class here for more details.

How it works internally is -  When a topology is created, you need to define a source, sink and processor using below methods:

`addSource()` , `addSink()`  and `addProcessor()`

These methods add the processor node in the topology and internally calls the [InternalTopologyBuilder](https://zgrepcode.com/kafka/apache/2.0/streams/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/internals/internalstreamsbuilder.java) class to build the Topology Graph.

On `streams.start()` method, it invokes the processing of the topology.